# TypeError: contract.totalSupply is not a function ERC721

Tags: json, function, solidity

me esta apareciendo este problema, en la creacion de un marketplace, ya que me esta generando un error de implementacion del `TypeError: contract.totalSupply no es una funcion en el index.js`, agrego los codigos para que me den ayuda Gracias.

contrato inteligente NFT ERC721

```html
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT OR Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
contract NFTGPAY is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter public _tokenIds;
    address contractAddress;
    uint256 public cost = 0.075 ether;
    constructor(address marketContract) ERC721("n2DMarket", "N2DM") {
        contractAddress = marketContract;
    }
    function createNFT(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return newItemId;
    }
    function mintNFT(string memory tokenURI) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(msg.value == cost, "Need to send 0.075 ether!");
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return newItemId;
    }
```

índice.js
para resumir el codigo, solo agrego la parte donde me dice que presento el error, quisiera ayuda

pages\index.js (34:13) @ _callee$

```
     **32 | const market = new ethers.Contract(hhresell, Resell, wallet);
      33 | const itemArray = [];
    > 34 | contract.totalSupply().then(result => {
         |         ^
      35 |   for (let i = 0; i < result; i++) {
      36 |     var token = i + 1         
      37 |     var owner = contract.ownerOf(token)**
```

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. No sabemos ni tenemos cómo saber dónde inicializas esa variable `contract` pero todo indica que su contenido no es una instancia de COntract o de lo que sea que deba tener, por lo que no tiene acceso a ningúñ método totalSuppy.

Comment: Hola! Cuando despliego en local la app, me genera el error que la función no está definida, ya que esa información la saca del json del contrato de erc721, lo que no entiendo el porqué genera ese error si no se está pidiendo ese dato en el erc721, este error sale en index.js, he pensado que de pronto no lo he definido en el index.js, no he mirado esa parte, pero puede ser una posibilidad?